# Given a finite collection of disjoint subsets of $I$ must every ultrafilter on $I$ contain exactly one?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, filters

The title pretty much contains the question, but here's some elaboration:

The following is one of the first results one encounters while learning about Ultrafilters.

**Fact:** If $\mathfrak{U}$ is an ultrafilter on an index set $I$, and $X\subset I$, then exactly one of $X$ and $I\backslash X$ is in $\mathfrak{U}$.

---

**Question:** Can this be generalized to a collection $X_{1}, ... X_{n}$ of disjoint subsets of $I$ for any $n\geq 1$?  That is, if $\mathfrak{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $I$, then there is exactly one value of $j\in\{1,...,n\}$ such that $X_{j}\in \mathfrak{U}$?

I haven't been able to find it in the literature anywhere or prove it myself (though I thought I did briefly) so I'm beginning to suspect it's false in general.

---

**Second Question:** If the answer to the first question is false, is it true if $\mathfrak{U}$ is an ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$ containing the order filter?

Comment: Yes, and in fact one can define ultrafilters this way. See, for example, Proposition 1.5 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.3606.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: You need the $X_i$ to be a partition. This is not what the OP asked (but it may be what they meant).

Comment: A partition is what I intended to start with, but forgot to mention.

Thanks to all for the great answers.

Comment: I was not sure whether to tag this ([tag:elementary-set-theory]) or ([tag:set-theory]). But since the [tag-info for set-theory](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/set-theory/info) explicitly mentions ultrafilters, I chose that one.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/493055/equivalent-characterizations-of-ultrafilters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X_1, \dots, X_n$ is a collection of disjoint sets with $\bigcup_{i=1}^nX_i = I$, then $X_k \in \mathfrak{U}$ for precisely one $k$.

Note that for each $k$, either $X_k \in \mathfrak{U}$ or $\bigcup_{i \neq k}X_i \in \mathfrak{U}$. If $X_k \not\in \mathfrak{U}$ for all $k$, then $\bigcup_{i\neq k}X_i \in \mathfrak{U}$ for every $k$, and so the intersection of such sets would also belong to $\mathfrak{U}$. This is a contradiction as the intersection is empty, i.e. $\bigcap_{k=1}^n\bigcup_{i\neq k}X_i = \emptyset$. Therefore, there exists $k \in \{1, \dots, n\}$ such that $X_k \in \mathfrak{U}$. If there were $l \in \{1, \dots, n\}$, $l \neq k$, with $X_l \in \mathfrak{U}$, then $X_l\cap X_k \in \mathfrak{U}$, but this intersection is empty, so no such $l$ exits. Therefore, $k$ is unique.

Note, you need the sets $X_i$ to cover $I$. If they don't cover $I$, choose $m \in I\setminus\bigcup_{i=1}^nX_i$ and consider the principal ultrafilter $\mathfrak{U}_m$. As $m \not\in X_i$ for all $i$, $X_i \not\in \mathfrak{U}_m$ for all $i$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ be a finite collection of sets (not necessarily pairwise disjoint) such that the union $X_1\cup X_2\cup \cdots\cup X_n$ is in the ultrafilter. Then at least one of the $X_i$ is in the ultrafilter. If the $X_i$ are pairwise disjoint, then exactly one of the $X_i$ is in the ultrafilter. The proof is straightforward, by induction.

**Added:** From comments, it became clear that the OP knew the standard proof that if $D$ is an ultrafilter on the index set $I$, then $X$ or $X^c$ is in $D$. The fact that if the union $X_1\cup X_2$ is in $D$, then $X_1$ or $X_2$ is in $D$ follows. For let $O$ be the "rest" of $I$. If $X_1$ is not in $D$, then its complement $X_2\cup O$ is in $D$. Also, we know that $X_1\cup X_2$ is in $D$. Now note that $X_2=(X_2\cup O)\cap(X_1\cup X_2)$, so $X_2\in D$.

**Remark:** I think it helps the intuition to think of an ultrafilter as defining a two-valued "measure" $\mu$ on the collection of subsets of $I$, where $\mu(X)=1$ if $X$ is in the ultrafilter, and $\mu(X)=0$ otherwise. The "measure" is almost always not a real measure, since it is ordinarily not countably additive. But it is finitely additive. The finite additivity makes the answer to your question clear.  If the $X_i$ all had measure $0$, their union would have measure $0$.

Comment: It is the intuition you describe that led me to guess that the result might be true.  I could not come up with a proof, however.  Thanks for your additional information!

Comment: To see how easy the induction is, let's do it for $3$ sets. Let $X_1\cup X_2\cup X_3$ be in the ultrafilter $D$. Then $(X_1\cup (X_2\cup X_3))\in D$. By the $n=2$ case, either $X_1\in D$, and we are finished, or $(X_2\cup X_3)\in D$, in which case again by the $n=2$ case we are finished.

Comment: I agree that the induction part of the proof is indeed easy.  But you are using the following lemma, which I think is the tricky part:  If $X_{1}\cup X_{2}\in \mathfrak{U}$, with $X_{1}\cap X_{2} = \phi$, then exactly one of $X_{1}$ or $X_{2}$ is in $\mathfrak{U}$.  This is slightly stronger than the fact I mentioned, and cannot be proved in quite the same way (using a brief maximality argument).  The lemma clearly follows immediately from Michael Albanese's argument above, but I do not see an easy way to get it directly.

Comment: That it cannot be both is obvious, for part of the usual definition of a filter $D$ is that $\emptyset\not\in D$.  For the proof that at least one is, it depends on the definition of ultrafilter. If we define it as a maximal filter, one shows that if neither $A$ nor $A^c$ is in $D$, then $A$ can be added to $D$, along with all intersections of elements of $D$ with $A$, and their supersets, to form a larger filter $D'$.

Comment: I agree with that argument (which proves the fact in my OP).  In fact it is the one I was referring to in my previous comment (with the adjustment that *either* $A$ or $A^{c}$ may be added to $D$, you don't know in advance which one).  But it doesn't work to prove the lemma mentioned above.  I will make an edit to my original post to clarify the distinction which is subtle.

Comment: What I'm getting at is that going from $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ forming a partition of $I$ to $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ forming a partition of *an element of* $\mathfrak{U}$ makes the details in the maximality argument not work anymore.  Nonetheless you can still prove this stronger statement by first proving what Michael Albanese shows above, and then deriving it as a Corollary.

Comment: Is it the part $O$ "outside" $X_1\cup X_2$ that bothers you? If $X_1$ is not in $D$, then its complement $X_2\cup O$ is in $D$, and by assumption $X_1\cup X_2$ is in $D$, so the intersection of $X_2\cup O$ and $X_1\cup X_2$ is in $D$, that is, $X_2$ is in $D$.

Comment: Very nice.  I take back everything I said.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

It is true, granted the sets form a partition of $I$. Otherwise it is easy to come by counterexamples, simple consider a few singletons and a free ultrafilter.

The proof is simple by induction.